# How to Check Full Access Enabled or not for IOS Custom Keyboard extension inside Container App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

Some people suggest setting value to UserDefaults from keyboard extension for this checking. But this procedure requires open the custom keyboard at least once. What about first time? Need a solid solution about this problem.

Comment: In container app i don't find any solution. inside extension found hasFullAccess method that only available from IOS11.